# Splitting the homepage screen to two screens

Tags: android

I'm new to Android. As a learning case, I'd like to build a software which divide the homepage screen to two screens.

The upper screen will displays an  updated whether data of a pre selected city, actually, airport and the lower screen will display the regular homepage screen.

How it can be done?

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to look into creating Widgets. 
[Have a looksie here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just [create a widget](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/widget_design.html)? And in that case, I believe there exist several weather widgets already.